# What type of tub cold water fill valve is this? I need to replace it due to leakage

Tags: bathtub, valve, cartridge

I've got a probably 50s-era tub fill valve that leaks substantially from the stem when turned on. The knob is labeled Kohler; what type/model of cartridge should I be looking for?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Kohler C model ..

Comment: thanks, replacement ordered

Comment: In general,  I've found that if I take the valve stem/cartridge to a local plumbing wholesaler they can always.ost always identify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of stem/cartridge does indeed seem to date from the 1950s. Since Kohler is/was such a big name, there are still as of 2023 some aftermarket replacements available. I am posting photos of some different ones that I found so people have an idea of what is inside the wall, and the difference between a replacement stem and a full stem+trim kit, as well as some part numbers to search for.

As of mid 2023, many of my usual go-to big stores were out of stock on these with no idea if they would be restocked, so hopefully this will provide people some ideas of what parts/names to search for - these are not endorsements, just examples only.

***Stem replacement, aftermarket by Lasco S-1125-3:***
(available within a few days)
[image]

***Stem replacement, aftermarket by Everbilt 35717***
(10 days to delivery)
[image]

***Stem and trim kit, aftermarket by Lincoln Products Model #
111868***
(7 days to delivery)
[image]

Finally, to unthread and rethread the stem in the wall, it seems to be useful to have a standard set of "shower valve sockets", which are not very expensive as tools go.
[image]